# How can I tell which button was pressed LAST - SWIFT?

Tags: swift, button, click

Pretty basic - I have multiple buttons and I just need to tell which button was pressed most recently, despite how many times on each or how long between clicks.

Comment: Assign a different tag to each button, and then in your button handler routines update a property called `lastButtonTag` with the tag of the button.

Answer (score 1):

- Give each button a unique tag in Interface Builder.
- Make a variable that holds the tag of the last button that has been clicked.
- In event handlers of your buttons set the variable from the step above to the tag of the button currently being clicked.
- When you need to find the last button that has been clicked, check the variable, it will have the unique tag of your button.

Comment: even better !! thnx